# problem with constraints in minimize from scipy.optimize

Tags: optimization, scipy

I have searched about this a bit, and couldn't solve this problem. I am working with the minimize function from scipy.optimize, and keep getting the error:

> 'str' object not callable.

My code is complicated, so I looked up an easy example online to make sure I was inputting everything correctly, and still got the same error. Here is the easy example I found on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXHvC_FGx24

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x):
    x1=x[0]
    x2=x[1]
    x3=x[2]
    x4=x[3]
    return x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3

def constraint1(x):
    return x[0]*x[1]*x[2]*x[3]-25

def constraint2(x):
    sum_sq = np.sum(np.square(x))
    return sum_sq-40


x0=[1,5,5,1]
b=(1, 5)
bnds = (b,b,b,b)
con1 = {'type':'ineq','fun':'constraint1'}
con2 = {'type':'eq','fun':'constraint2'}
cons=[con1,con2]

sol=minimize(objective, x0, method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds,constraints=cons)
```

This is code directly from an example on youtube, that appears to be working correctly on someone else's machine, but not mine.  What have I got wrong here?

[EDIT: If I remove the contraints, then it works fine.  What is wrong with the way I am entering the constraint functions?]

Thank you so much for the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in your constraints. You're passing a string instead of the functions for your constraints. Just change it to:

```
con1 = {'type':'ineq','fun': constraint1 }
con2 = {'type':'eq','fun': constraint2 }
cons=[con1,con2]
```

Comment: Oh Gawd.  I have been looking at this forever, I don't know how I missed that.  Thanks for the quick reply and I am sorry for the dumb question!

Comment: @gpsimms: please accept the answer if it solved your problem (click on the check next to the answer which then will turn green). It is also good practice to also upvote useful answers.